# Magento get related products not having all attributes loaded

Tags: php, magento, orm, magento-1.9, entity-attribute-value

i'm taking over a project and saw that the previous developer added a custom related products association. So he implemented a function to get the associated collection looking like this

```
/**
 * Retrieve collection CustomRelated product
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Link_Product_Collection
 */
public function getCustomRelatedProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->getLinkInstance()->useCustomRelatedLinks()
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->setIsStrongMode();
    $collection->setProduct($this);
    return $collection;
}
```

Then in phtml file, he's calling it out like this

```
$upsell_products = $_product->getCustomRelatedProductCollection();
```

And then he uses that collection in a foreach, and each element in the collection is using model 'catalog/product', but somehow it's not loading enough attributes like prices and name

It will load all of the attributes only when i call load function again like this

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($p->getId())
```

Which i don't want to do because it's pointless to reload the model, i'm still new to Magento so i'm not sure how to make the get collection above to fully load the product model, any ideas?

Comment: are you trying to get related products? or are you trying to get associated products? which one?

Comment: @Nickool Can you help explain the difference between the 2? The previous developer implemented a custom association between products, so i don't know if it should be called related or associated, something like if you buys this you will also like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load require attributes (name, price) like below.

```
public function getCustomRelatedProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->getLinkInstance()->useCustomRelatedLinks()
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array("name", "price")) 
        ->setIsStrongMode();
    $collection->setProduct($this);
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, but it's the same answer with Jitendra and i can only mark 1 answer as solution

Comment: Its ok. No issue. Just for your information, This is a best way to load collection with required attributes only. If you select using '*', It is load collection with all the attributes. So there is a query performance issue if we have many attributes are in a database.

Answer (score 2):

//I have added new line in your code. please check now.

```
public function getCustomRelatedProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->getLinkInstance()->useCustomRelatedLinks()
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->setIsStrongMode();
    $collection->setProduct($this);
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //New line added by me.
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Why isn't it defaulted to "select *" tho?